# How do I correctly calculate age in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to make a button calculate different equations.

What I have is any number I put into a text field it gets multiplied by 7.

But I'm looking to change it completely: I'd like to remove the multiply function altogether.

If the user enters 1 then the button press simply shows 7
If the user enters 2 then the button press simply shows 8
If the user enters 3 then the button press simply shows 9

Basically put canned responses in for 10 options (the user will be asked to enter 1 - 10) and I'll spit out the appropriate answer in a label box.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var CatAge: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var age = CatAge.text.toInt()
        age = age! * 7
        message.text = "Thats equal to \(age!) in cat years"
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `switch` statement? Or maybe a dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly, all you want it to do is add 6 to whatever they type in. In that case, your answer is simple:

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var age: Int = CatAge.text.toInt()!
    age += 6
    message.text = "Thats equal to \(age) in cat years"
}
```

Otherwise, if you're looking for something more dependent on what they actually type in, you might be looking for a [`switch` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-XID_1054), which goes something like this:

```
switch age {
    case 1:
        age = 7
    case 2:
        age = 10
    case 3:
        age = 15
    case 4:
        age = 22
    case 5:
        age = 27
    case 6:
        age = 33
    case 7:
        age = 40
    case 8:
        age = 46
    case 9:
        age = 51
    case 10:
        age = 60
    default:
        age = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this simply with a dictionary.

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let convert = [1:7, 2:8, 3:9, 4:10, 5:11, 6:12, 7:13, 8:14, 9:15, 10:16]
    if let age = convert[CatAge.text.toInt() ?? 0] {
        message.text = "Thats equal to \(age) in cat years"
    } else {
        message.text = "Invalid value"
    }
}
```

Here I have used the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap `CatAge.text.toInt()` if there is a value, otherwise it will be `0` if the text field couldn't be converted to an `Int`.  If the text field contains an `Int` that isn't in the dictionary, then the lookup in `convert` will return `nil`.  In that case, the optional binding will fail and the message will be "Invalid value".